# PDF viewer and/or reader having feature to play animations

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu, pdf-viewer

I’m looking for a PDF viewer for Ubuntu 14.04 to play animation of plots (Fig. 7, page 4 and page 9) in [knitr-graphics.pdf](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/).

[Link to download PDF file](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/download/doc/knitr-graphics.pdf).

For Windows I was using [Adobe Reader](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/products/pdf-reader.html). Now I need something similar to Adobe Reader for Ubuntu.

Comment: Are those animation created using `\animategraphics` in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested Adobe Reader on Ubuntu 14.04 and the animation on page 9 works fine. See [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-1404/) to install it.

I use [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/german/products/reader/) (on Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 with Wine) and [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) and neither show the animations similar to you which I create using LaTeX.  Abobe Reader is the only thing that works for me on any Windows and Linux (not a Mac user).

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no (Free) PDF viewer for Ubuntu which is able to display these animations.

You'll have to install Adobe Reader for Linux (the latest version available is 9, no more officially supported, neither by Adobe nor by Ubuntu).

Neither PDF.js (Firefox's built-in PDF renderer) or PDFium (Chrome's built-in PDF renderer), nor MuPDF, XPDF, Evince, Okular or Zathura support these animations. (Preview.app on Mac OS X doesn't support it either...)

For the other payware vendors, Foxit and Nitro: their readers aren't available for Linux....

Comment: Great @stvn66. Would you mind to change your comment to answer. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: the accepted answer basically is the same as mine, only 3 days later...